# regular expression confusion \s and " "

Tags: regex

In regular expression, i know when use \s to represent a space, but, in following case, would they be different:

1. /a\sb/ ---with a \s
2. /a b/  ---with empty field

thanks a lot if you can explain to me.

Comment: The regex engine you're using is extremely relevant.

Comment: In modern regex: `\s` is a space, not `/s`

Comment: And in most it matches any whitespace, not just spaces, but not in all.

Comment: my bad, I have changed to \s. I mean \s and "a real space" are different or not. I know it's a odd question, but it still bugs me a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The \s character class matches all "whitespace characters," not just spaces.  This includes tabs (\t), and if multiline matching is allowed, it includes carriage return (\r) and newline (\n).  Theoretically, if your regular expression engine handles unicode, there are also unicode whitespace characters that \s can match, though your mileage may vary.

So with a string like "a\t b", you can match it with the regex /a\s+b/, in case that is useful to you.

Comment: A helpful PHP snippit to replace all "whitespace characters", including multiple spaces, with a single space:
  $str = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str);